# CS50 Substitution - Does not output ciphertext - logic error

Tags: c, cs50, substitution

The function of the program is to be run with a command-line argument, for example, might be the string *NQXPOMAFTRHLZGECYJIUWSKDVB*. This 26-character key means that *A* (the first letter of the alphabet) should be converted into *N* (the first character of the key), *B* (the second letter of the alphabet) should be converted into *Q* (the second character of the key), and so forth. A message like *HELLO*, then, would be encrypted as *FOLLE*, replacing each of the letters according to the mapping determined by the key.

e.g.

> ./substitution JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ

> plaintext:  HELLO

> ciphertext: VKXXN*

After starting the program with a valid command-line argument, the program doesn't output anything. It should output the ciphertext which has been encrypted using the key. I can't seem to find where the logic error is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool is_valid_key(string plaintext);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Error message if user inputs incorret comand-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!is_valid_key(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //Prompts user for plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
    string difference = argv[1];
    for (int i = 'A'; i < 'Z'; i++)
    {
        difference[i - 'A'] = toupper(difference[i - 'A']) - i;
    }
    printf("Ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            plaintext[i] = plaintext[i] + difference[plaintext[i] - (isupper(plaintext[i]) ? 'A' : 'a')];
        }
        printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Checks vailidity of the key
bool is_valid_key(string plaintext)
{
    int len = strlen(plaintext);
    if (len != 26)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    int freq[26] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        int index = toupper(plaintext[i]) - 'A';
        if (freq[index] > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        freq[index]++;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `int len = strlen(plaintext);`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`

Comment: Are you sure the program is not outputting anything? I got both the answers, ``FOLLE`` and ``VKXXN``, with your program.

Comment: Are you executing the program from a persistent commandline? I.e. can you call it, see nothing being printed and then still see the commandline which you used to call the program? This would be in contrast to executing it from GUI, have a temporary console appear for too short a time to notice and miss seeing it before it immiediatly closes again. I.e there might be an output which you with your slow human eye, just don't see.

Comment: I compiled the posted code under linux with gcc.  The result was 4 warning messages about conversion from `int` to `char`, which I ignored.  then ran several test runs.  They all worked correctly

Comment: I ran the program using the CS50 IDE (ide.cs50.io), it has a persistent command-line. I managed to fix most of the errors I was getting by correcting a small mistake I made on line 29, which should have been ```printf("ciphertext: ");``` lol. However, when I ran check50 (check50 cs50/problems/2020/x/substitution), 2 inputs didn't output correctly. (encrypts "XyZ" as "KeD" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key
    output not valid ASCII text). (encrypts all alphabetic characters using DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM as key
    output not valid ASCII text).

Comment: I have managed to locate the final bug which caused the previous errors. The logic error was on line 25, it should have been ```for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)```. Thank you, everyone for trying to help. I appreciate it a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Line 25 should have been `for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)`.
Line 29 should have been `printf("ciphertext: ");`